# How to achieve createDrawerNavigator inside createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am working on a app where I gave a bottom tabs on my home screen. I have successfully implemented the bottom navigation which is navigating to multiple screen. However, I want to open a side drawer from one of the bottom tabs.

This is what I've done so far:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  { DrawerScreen: { screen: SideDrawer } },
  { drawerPosition: "right", drawerWidth: 300 }
);

const mainBottomStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: mainStack,
    MedicalRecord: MedicalRecordStack,
    //MedicalRecord: PatientDetails,
    Visit: VisitStack,
    Alerts: AlertStack,
    Profile: PatientDetails,
    Settings: Drawer // This tabs is navigates to drawer
  },
  {
    transitionConfig,
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#694fad" },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
        navigation.state.routeName == "Home" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/Home.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : navigation.state.routeName == "MedicalRecord" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/Medicalhistory.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : navigation.state.routeName == "Profile" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/avatar-dark.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : navigation.state.routeName == "Visit" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/CalenderVisit.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : navigation.state.routeName == "Alerts" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/Notificationbell.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : navigation.state.routeName == "Settings" ? (
          <Image
            source={require("../images/BottomMenu/menubar.png")}
            style={{ opacity: focused ? 1 : 0.5, width: 23, height: 23 }}
          />
        ) : null
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: "grey",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray",
      activeBackgroundColor: "white",
      inactiveBackgroundColor: "white",
      horizontal: false,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 9
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: styles.themeColor.color,
        borderTopWidth: 0
        // height:50
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The issue that I'm facing is when I touch to open the drawer the view open on the entire drawer which doesn't look like a drawer and looks more like a screen with no headers.

What am I doing wrong here?